# How to get active class for pagination when it is on the first page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am troubled to get active class when not paging, I mean when the user on the first page? The concept is when user come on the posts page then default active pagination 1, here below is my code

```
let pageNum = 'undefined' // it goes 2, 3, 4 when pagination clicked
let totalPages = 4

const pager = () => {
    const paginate = []

    for(let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++){
        paginate.push(
            <Link href={`?page=${i}`} key={i}>
                <a 
                    className={
                        `page-numbers ${(parseInt(pageNum) === i) ? 'current' : null}`
                    }
                >
                    {i}
                </a>
            </Link>
        )
    }
    return paginate
}


// render
{pager()}
```

The above code is working well even get active pagination number when pagination clicked but not in default active, how do I do that?

Note: please suggest me if I have done wrong in this question like a formate update or anything confusion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you initializing `pageNum` as `undefined`? Shouldn't it be initialized to `1` (by default, you load the first page of your pagination)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `let pageNum = 'undefined'` to `let pageNum = 1`.
If you do this you can also remove the `parseInt` function.